# Soap webservice giving noreponse in ios

Tags: ios

I have one soap webservice that runs completely on android and in a browser but when we integrate that webservice in ios it returns status code 200 but no data returns 
so it is related to some webservice or some ios fault,

here is the code:

```
#import "ServerAPI.h"
#import "SharedObjects.h"
#import "TouchXML.h"

@implementation ServerAPI
@synthesize engine;
@synthesize receivedData;

+ (ServerAPI *)api;
{
    static ServerAPI *api;
    if (nil != api)
        return api;
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        api = [[ServerAPI alloc] init];
    });

    return api;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        engine = [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:kServerHOST customHeaderFields:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString*)scriptPathForAction:(kActionType)type {
    switch (type) {
        case kActionTypeGetListing:
            return @"GetListing";
        case kActionTypeGetListings:
            return @"GetListings";
        case kActionTypeGetMoreListings:
            return @"GetMoreListings";
        case kActionTypeLike:
            return @"Like";
        case kActionTypeMarkExpired:
            return @"MarkExpired";
        case kActionTypeMarkSpam:
            return @"MarkSpam";
        case kActionTypeUnLike:
            return @"UnLike";
        case kActionTypeUploadFile:
            return @"UploadFile";
        case kActionTypeAddComment:
            return @"Comment";
        case kActionTypeDeleteComment:
            return @"DeleteComment";
        case kActionTypeAddListing:
            return @"AddListing";
        case kActionTypeCheckIfListingExist:
            return @"CheckIfListingExist";
        case kActionTypeAddUser:
            return @"AddUser";

    }
}


- (void)executeAction:(kActionType)type withParams:(NSDictionary*)params onCompletion:(APIResponseBlock)completionBlock onError:(APIErrorBlock)errorBlock onValidationError:(APIErrorValidationBlock)validationErrorBlock {
    if (apiResponseBlock) {
        [apiResponseBlock release];
        apiResponseBlock = nil;
    }
    if (apiErrorBlock) {
        [apiErrorBlock release];
        apiErrorBlock = nil;
    }

    apiResponseBlock = [completionBlock copy];
    apiErrorBlock = [errorBlock copy];
    NSString *XMLNameSpace = kServerNameSpace;
    NSString *XMLURLAddress = [kServerHOST stringByAppendingPathComponent:kServerPATH];
    NSString *MethodName = [self scriptPathForAction:type];

    NSMutableDictionary *postValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [postValues addEntriesFromDictionary:params];
    postValues[@"hashvalue"] = kServerAPIHash;
    progressView = nil;
    if ([postValues objectForKey:@"increment"]) {
        type = kActionTypeGetListings;
    }

    if (type == kActionTypeAddListing) {
        PoiItem *p = params[@"newPoi"];
        postValues[@"title"] = p.name;
        postValues[@"description"] = p.name;
        postValues[@"address"] = p.address;
        postValues[@"price"] = p.price;
        postValues[@"discount"] = p.discount;
        postValues[@"website"] = p.website;
        postValues[@"phone"] = p.phone;
        postValues[@"opening_hours"] = p.opening_hours;
        postValues[@"entry_cost"] = p.entry_cost;
        NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",p.location.latitude];
        NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",p.location.longitude];
        postValues[@"longitude"] = lon;
        postValues[@"latitude"] = lat;
        [[SharedObjects objects].df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        if (!p.dateFrom)
            postValues[@"start_date"] = @"";
        else
            postValues[@"start_date"] = [[SharedObjects objects].df stringFromDate:p.dateFrom];
        if (!p.dateUntil)
            postValues[@"end_date"] = @"";
        else
            postValues[@"end_date"] = [[SharedObjects objects].df stringFromDate:p.dateUntil];
        [postValues removeObjectForKey:@"newPoi"];
    }

    if (type == kActionTypeUploadFile) {
        progressView = [params[@"progress"] retain];

        NSData *attachData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:params[@"filepath"]];
        if (attachData) {
            postValues[@"f"] = [attachData base64EncodedString];
        }
        [postValues removeObjectForKey:@"filepath"];
        [postValues removeObjectForKey:@"progress"];

    }
    NSLog(@"post values %@",postValues);

    NSMutableString *sRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSString *SOAPActionURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", XMLNameSpace, MethodName];

    //make soap request
    [sRequest appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ xmlns=\"%@\">",MethodName, XMLNameSpace]];

    [postValues enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [sRequest appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", key, obj, key]];
    }];

    //close envelope
    [sRequest appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>", MethodName]];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Envelope>"];


    NSURL *myWebserverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:XMLURLAddress];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myWebserverURL];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:SOAPActionURL forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [sRequest release];

    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    currentType = type;
    activeConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;

    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    //NSLog(@"webdata: %@", data);

}


- (void)unlockErrorSilence {
    errorIsShown = NO;
}
- (void)showNetworkError:(NSString*)message {
    if (errorIsShown)
        return;
    errorIsShown = YES;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection error" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(unlockErrorSilence) withObject:nil afterDelay:kErrorSilenceInterval];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error with the connection");
    [self showNetworkError:error.localizedDescription];
    [connection release];
    activeConnection = nil;
    apiErrorBlock(error);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    float progressValue = (float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    progressView.progress = progressValue;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"response %@",[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
    CXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          kServerNameSpace,
                          @"namespace",
                          nil];

    if (currentType == kActionTypeMarkExpired) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:MarkExpiredResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *likeError = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (likeError.length>0)
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:likeError}]);
            else
                apiResponseBlock(nil);
        }
    }
    if (currentType == kActionTypeMarkSpam) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:MarkSpamResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *likeError = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (likeError.length>0)
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:likeError}]);
            else
                apiResponseBlock(nil);
        }
    }
    if (currentType == kActionTypeLike) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:LikeResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *likeError = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (likeError.length>0)
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:likeError}]);
            else
                apiResponseBlock(nil);
        }
    }

    if (currentType == kActionTypeAddComment) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:CommentResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *addedID = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (addedID.length>0)
                apiResponseBlock(@{@"addedCommentID":addedID});
            else
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Error during posting comment"}]);
        }
    }

    if (currentType == kActionTypeDeleteComment) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:DeleteCommentResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *likeError = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (likeError.length>0)
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:likeError}]);
            else
                apiResponseBlock(nil);
        }
    }
    if (currentType == kActionTypeUnLike) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:UnLikeResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            NSString *likeError = [[[[nodes lastObject] elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (likeError.length>0)
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:likeError}]);
            else
                apiResponseBlock(nil);
        }
    }

    if (currentType == kActionTypeUploadFile) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:UploadFileResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            CXMLElement *resp = nodes[0];
            NSString *uploadedFileName = [[[resp elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (uploadedFileName) {
                apiResponseBlock(@{@"uploadedFileName":uploadedFileName});
            }
            else
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Error uploading photo"}]);
        }
    }

    if (currentType == kActionTypeAddUser) {
        apiResponseBlock(nil);
    }
    if (currentType == kActionTypeAddListing) {
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:AddListingResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (nodes.count>0) {
            CXMLElement *resp = nodes[0];
            NSString *addedID = [[[resp elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
            if (addedID) {
                apiResponseBlock(@{@"addedID":addedID});
            }
            else
                apiErrorBlock([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.hotspot" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Error adding listing"}]);
        }
    }

    if (currentType == kActionTypeCheckIfListingExist) {


        // Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:BO1" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (currentType == kActionTypeGetListing) {
            nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:CheckIfListingExistResponse" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        }
        NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
        [nodes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CXMLElement *l, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            PoiItem *new = [PoiItem new];
            new.ID = @([[[[l elementsForName:@"id"] lastObject] stringValue] intValue]);
            new.name = [[[l elementsForName:@"title"] lastObject] stringValue];
            [results addObject:new];
            [new release];
        }];

        apiResponseBlock(@{@"content":results});
    }


    if (currentType == kActionTypeGetListings || currentType == kActionTypeGetListing) {


        // Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
        NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:BO1" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        if (currentType == kActionTypeGetListing) {
            nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//namespace:GetListingResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
        }
        NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
        [nodes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CXMLElement *l, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            PoiItem *new = [PoiItem new];
            new.ID = @([[[[l elementsForName:@"id"] lastObject] stringValue] intValue]);
            new.name = [[[l elementsForName:@"title"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.descriptionText = [[[l elementsForName:@"description"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.categoryCoverURL = [[[l elementsForName:@"cat_pic_url"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.address = [[[l elementsForName:@"address"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.website = [[[l elementsForName:@"website"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.phone = [[[l elementsForName:@"phone"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.discount = [[[l elementsForName:@"discount"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.entry_cost = [[[l elementsForName:@"entry_cost"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.opening_hours = [[[l elementsForName:@"opening_hours"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.event_date = [[[l elementsForName:@"event_date"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.thumbsup = @([[[[l elementsForName:@"thumbsup"] lastObject] stringValue] intValue]);
            new.thumbsdown = @([[[[l elementsForName:@"thumbsdown"] lastObject] stringValue] intValue]);
            float distance = [[[[l elementsForName:@"distance"] lastObject] stringValue] floatValue];
            new.distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f km ",distance];

            NSString *lat = [[[l elementsForName:@"latitude"] lastObject] stringValue];
            NSString *lon = [[[l elementsForName:@"longitude"] lastObject] stringValue];
            new.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lon doubleValue]);

            NSArray *attachments = [l elementsForName:@"images"];
            [new.attachments removeAllObjects];
            for (CXMLElement *image in attachments) {
                NSString *newURL = [[[image elementsForName:@"string"] lastObject] stringValue];
                [new.attachments addObject:newURL];
            }
            [new setAttachments:new.attachments];
            if (new.attachments.count>1) {
                NSLog(@"IMAGESSS %@",new.name);
            }
            NSArray *allFriends = [l elementsForName:@"liked_friends"];
            CXMLElement *allFriendsContainer = [allFriends lastObject];
            NSArray *likes =  [allFriendsContainer elementsForName:@"User"];
            [new.friendsLiked removeAllObjects];

            for (CXMLElement *user in likes) {
                UserItem *newUser = [UserItem new];
                newUser.name = [[[user elementsForName:@"name"] lastObject] stringValue];
                newUser.facebookLink = [[[user elementsForName:@"fblink"] lastObject] stringValue];
          //      newUser.facebookLink = @"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1319733500";
                NSString *cleanFbLink = [NSString stringWithString:newUser.facebookLink];
                cleanFbLink = [cleanFbLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"profile.php?id=" withString:@""];
                NSString *facebookUserID = cleanFbLink.lastPathComponent;
                newUser.coverURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",facebookUserID];
//                [new.friendsLiked addObject:newUser];
//                [new.friendsLiked addObject:newUser];
//                [new.friendsLiked addObject:newUser];
                [new.friendsLiked addObject:newUser];
                [newUser release];
            }

            NSArray *allComments = [l elementsForName:@"comments"];
            CXMLElement *allCommentsContainer = [allComments lastObject];
            NSArray *comments =  [allCommentsContainer elementsForName:@"Comment"];
            [new.comments removeAllObjects];

            [[SharedObjects objects].df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
            for (CXMLElement *comment in comments) {
                CommentItem *newComment = [CommentItem new];
                newComment.ID = [[[comment elementsForName:@"id"] lastObject] stringValue];
                newComment.descriptionText = [[[comment elementsForName:@"text"] lastObject] stringValue];
                NSString *dateString = [[[comment elementsForName:@"date"] lastObject] stringValue];
                newComment.postedDate = [[SharedObjects objects].df dateFromString:dateString];
                CXMLElement *user = [[comment elementsForName:@"commented_user"] lastObject];
                newComment.creatorName = [[[user elementsForName:@"name"] lastObject] stringValue];
                newComment.creatorURL = [[[user elementsForName:@"fblink"] lastObject] stringValue];

                NSString *cleanFbLink = [NSString stringWithString:newComment.creatorURL];
                cleanFbLink = [cleanFbLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"profile.php?id=?" withString:@""];
                NSString *facebookUserID = cleanFbLink.lastPathComponent;
                newComment.coverURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",facebookUserID];

                [new.comments addObject:newComment];
                [newComment release];
                NSLog(@"adding comment text %@ %@ %@ %@",newComment.descriptionText,newComment.creatorName,newComment.creatorURL,newComment.postedDate);
            }
            [results addObject:new];
            [new release];
        }];
        apiResponseBlock(@{@"content":results,@"total":@"99999"});
    }


    [xmlDoc release];
    [connection release];
    activeConnection = nil;

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
}

@end
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more details. How are you calling the web service? How are you attempting to read the response body data? Maybe show some code.

Comment: hi brother i am not ios devloper but i can give you file that is using,it is not going under didReceiveData

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

should be:

```
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: hi, i have changed that line but still have same problem